# Variational form for inner product bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be any PSD matrix and $x$ be any unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Can someone help me understand why the following statement is true: \begin{equation}
\max_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d}\{\theta^\top x\colon ~ \theta^\top A \theta \leq 1 \} = \|x\|_{A^{-1}}
\end{equation}

This seems to follow trivially from the definition of $\|x\|_{A^{-1}}$ but its unclear to me how it follows from $\|x\|^2_{A^{-1}} = x^\top A^{-1} x$. Is there a variational definition for $\|x\|_{A^{-1}}$? Thanks!

Comment: First, remove the $\epsilon$. It is enough to prove the formula with $\epsilon=1$, by rescaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $A$ is invertible, apparently.  Presumably, we also know that $A$ is symmetric.

With that, let $\psi := A^{1/2} \theta$.  We find that $\theta^Tx = \psi^TA^{-1/2}x$, and $\theta^T A \theta = \|\psi\|^2$.  Thus,
$$
\max_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d}\{\theta^\top x\colon ~ \theta^\top A \theta \leq 1 \} = 
\max_{\psi \in \Bbb R^d} \{\psi^T[A^{-1/2}x]:\|\psi\|^2 \leq 1\}.
$$
We note that this maximum must be attained when $\|\psi\|^2 = 1$, so we can simply consider the problem
$$
\max_{\psi \in \Bbb R^d} \{\psi^T[A^{-1/2}x]:\|\psi\|^2 = 1\}.
$$

It now suffices to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  In particular, we have
$$
\psi^T[A^{-1/2}x] \leq \|\psi\| \cdot \|A^{-1/2}x\| = \|A^{-1/2}x\|.
$$
and this inequality becomes an equation when $\psi$ is a multiple of $A^{-1/2}x$ (so this upper bound is attained).

Now, we have
$$
\|A^{-1/2}x\|^2 = (A^{-1/2}x)^T(A^{-1/2}x) = x^TA^{-1}x = \|x\|_{A^{-1}}^2.
$$
So, the maximum is indeed $\|x\|_{A^{-1}}$ (which is equal to $\|A^{-1/2}x\|$) as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!